# Como mostrar ID do Firebase do usuário conectado na tela?

Tags: java, firebase

Preciso pegar o getUid do usuário conectado e setar o id em um editText. Deixei abaixo só para mostrar o que quero fazer, porque dessa forma não funciona. Como posso chamar um getUid conectado em qualquer parte do código e setar ele como EditText?

```
private EditText userId;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener minhaAuthListener;

userId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userId);


 minhaAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            Log.d("meuLog", "Usuário conectado: " + user.getUid());
            userId.setText(user.getUid());
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma.

```
    FirebaseUser user1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user1 != null) {
        for (UserInfo profile : user1.getProviderData()) {
            // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
            String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
            // UID specific to the provider
            String uid = user1.getUid();
            userId.setText(uid);
        }
    }
```